# How to do a comparative analysis of electrical characteristics of two 134kHz RFID circuits?

Tags: circuit-analysis, antenna, rfid, telecommunications, resonator

In the figure below there are two antenna circuits, both are circuits used in RFID at 134kHz, which are external to the [TMS3705](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tms3705.pdf?ts=1645104664517&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) IC. Circuit number **1** is an old circuit, circuit number **2** is the circuit that replaced it, in it I can change the component values.

[image]

I would like to do a comparative analysis of electrical characteristics between the two circuits, in order to perhaps adjust the components of circuit **2** so that their parameters become equal or close to those of circuit **1**.

Circuit parameters I can imagine would be:

- Q quality factor
- Resonance frequency
- Time constants etc.

Would anyone know how to make a comparative analysis of electrical characteristics between the two circuits?

Comment: This is what simulators are for!

Comment: I would like a method that is not a try-and - error process

Comment: The simulator will solve a zillion equations in real time vs you armed with a calculator. Which one is likely to error? Set up the simulation and sweep the frequency in the expected range. You’ll be able to determine resonance, Q , bandwidth, impedance etc. Repeat with signal gen and real hardware. Not sure if the nanoVNA goes low enough for your application - i used it for HF rfid testing.

Comment: Which simulator would you recommend?